# Node.JS Express Promise Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a Node.JS/Express application. I am using Jade as the template engine. I am experiencing some strange behavior.

I have a mock API that returns a simply array to my Jade template. I have verified the API works from a server perspective. However, whenever I start the server the first time I go to that specific page I receive an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at routes.js:28:34
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\dev\code\javascript\ps_resume_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\dev\code\javascript\ps_resume_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\dev\code\javascript\ps_resume_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\dev\code\javascript\ps_resume_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\dev\code\javascript\ps_resume_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\dev\code\javascript\ps_resume_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (E:\dev\code\javascript\ps_resume_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at Function.handle (E:\dev\code\javascript\ps_resume_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
    at router (E:\dev\code\javascript\ps_resume_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
```

This happens every time I start the start the server. However, as long as it stays running, subsequent calls work and the page is properly rendered.

Here is my route method is

```
router.get('/skills', (req, res) => {
      console.log('received request for skills');
      resumeAPI.getAllSkills().then((skills) => {
        console.log("inside then skills length " + skills.length);
        properties.skills = skills;
        console.log("inside then properties.skills length " + properties.skills.length);
      });
      console.log("outside promise skills length " + properties.skills.length);
      properties.heading = 'Skills';
      res.render('skills', properties)
    });
```

I put in the console.log lines to try and capture what is going on.

My API method is as follows

```
class ResumeApi {
  static getAllSkills() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("from api skills " + skills.length);
      resolve(skills);
    });
  }
}
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: `res.render('skills', properties)` should be inside `then` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `console.log("outside promise skills length " + properties.skills.length)` will run before the asynchronous operation finishes it's execution, so do not expect it to be something different than undefined. You can't access the `skills` property outside the promise in such a case.

You need to put the `res.render` inside `.then()` method of `getAllSkills()` execution

```
router.get('/skills', (req, res) => {
  resumeAPI.getAllSkills().then((skills) => {
    properties.skills = skills;

    // res.render goes HERE, otherwise it will not have the skills property inside properties object
    properties.heading = 'Skills';
    res.render('skills', properties)
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe I didn't see that and that oi made that dumb of a mistake.